# How to replace first two characters in string

Tags: excel, vba

i want to change the first two characters in intire row A and number them from 1 to end (so like DE-1 DE-2 DE-3 DE-4 DE-5) if row C starts with 49

```
If Cells(myRow, "C") Like "49*" Then
        Cells(myRow, "A") = "DE-"
```

Comment: I'm curious how you are going to use the result. It might be a lot easier to do the transformation with Power Query (Data tab> Get & Transform) compared to using VBA, but of course you will then get a new table with the result.

Comment: I dont know how to use that

Comment: 'C' is by definition not a 'Row' ? Your question says 'I want to change the first two characters' but the example shows adding characters to it? I.e. going from `49*` (??) to `DE-1, DE-2, DE-3` etc.? Include some sample data and try some actual code perhaps? Maybe look at using `Replace()`

Comment: You haven't shared enough information. Please share your complete code and add screenshots of your data before and after.

Comment: maybe `For Each cell In Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlConstants)` ... next line `If Left(cell.Value, 2) = "49" Then cnt = cnt + 1: cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "DE-" & cnt` ... next line : `next`. It loop to each cell which has value in column C. Then it check if the first 2 char of the looped cell value is 49 then it put "DE-" with an increment number in column A of the respected row. So if for example at cell C100 it's the twentieth times a value with first two char "49" appear in column C, then cell A100 value is "DE-20".

Answer (score 0):

Code as per your requirements:

```
'Code will check of your row and Column C if starts with 49 then put DE-Column Number upto last Column with Data
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim myCol, myRow As Long
myRow = 3    'Update row number as per your requirements
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
For myCol = 1 To LastCol
    If Cells(myRow, "C") Like "49*" Then
        Cells(myRow, myCol) = "DE-" & myCol
    End If
Next myCol
```